# Magento order tracking error. "parameter $date must be set, null is not allowed"

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, zend-framework

Using Magento 1.9.1.0. When I open the order shipping tracking I get this error:

```
There has been an error processing your request 
parameter $date must be set, null is not allowed
```

The full output is this:

```
    Trace:
    #0 /public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(1091): Zend_Date->_calculate('set', NULL, 'U', 'nb_NO')
    #1 /public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php(210): Zend_Date->set(NULL, 'U', 'nb_NO')
    #2 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(524): Zend_Date->__construct(NULL, 'U', Object(Zend_Locale))
    #3 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Block/Tracking/Popup.php(245): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->date(false, 'U', NULL, false)
    #4 /public_html/app/design/frontend/gravdept/acumen/template/shipping/tracking/popup.phtml(142): Mage_Shipping_Block_Tracking_Popup->formatDeliveryTime('10:37:00', '14. okt. 2015')
    #5 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/...')
    #6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/gravde...')
    #7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
    #11 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
    #13 /public_html/app/design/frontend/gravdept/acumen/template/page/popup.phtml(29): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
    #14 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/...')
    #15 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/gravde...')
    #16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
    #17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
    #18 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #19 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
    #20 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/controllers/TrackingController.php(76): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #21 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Shipping_TrackingController->popupAction()
    #22 /public_html/var/cache/ew/files/69/b9/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('popup')
    #23 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_StandardOverriddenClass->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #24 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #25 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #26 /public_html/index.php(100): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #27 {main}
```

This happened from one order to the next, and has been the case with every order since. Tracking earlier orders still works. Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*14. okt. 2015* is not valid in English date format as required by [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). That's why it cannot be parsed for further usage with `Zend_Date`.

As this second parameter is not required for `Mage_Shipping_Block_Tracking_Popup::formatDeliveryTime()`, just remove it from your custom popup template and you are done.

Comment: @cedjud i have the same problem , how i can solve it ?